# What is the first chmod octal digit in a four-digit value for?

Tags: chmod

Sometimes I see `chmod` commands that use four octal digits instead of three -- what is the optional first digit for? For example, `chmod 777` is equivalent to `chmod a+rwx`; what's the same command for `chmod 2777`?

Comment: This is a good question, so I tried to generalize it a bit

Comment: The 'fourth chmod octal digit' is a bit confusing, the digit in question is actually the first when reading from left to right.

Comment: How have only 50 people wondered this same question?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Please note that `chmod 777 filename` is the equivalent of `chmod 0777 filename` in this example.

The first octal digit sets the setuid, setgid and sticky bits (see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) for more details on setuid/setgid).  octal 2 means to set group ID on the file.  So, the equivalent would be to do a `chmod a+rwx filename`, then `chmod g+s filename`.  The `chmod` [info page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html) does explain this in more detail.

Comment: Nearly all implementations of *chmod(1)* can use commas in symbolic mode arguments. Thus, your equivalent of 2777 can be done in one command: `chmod a+rwx,g+s filename`. Or, more strictly (being sure to clear the setuid and sticky bits as the numeric mode would): `chmod a=rwx,g+s filename`.